# Gives me an error while creating an object in java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I faced an error while creating my object using a defined class in Java.
Here is my code:

```
public class encapsulation {

    class Emp
    {
        int empId;
        String empName;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)   
    {
        Emp e1 = new Emp();
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> No enclosing instance of type encapsulation is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type encapsulation (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of encapsulation).

Here is a screeshot: [Error in object creation using java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpLXR.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to instantiate an object of an inner class. Inner class instances always need to be associated with an outer class instance. Try this -

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    encapsulation en = new encapsulation();
    encapsulation.Emp e1 = en.new Emp();
}
```

Check out [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an inner class `Emp` in `encapsulation`, any *instance* of `Emp` belongs to an *instance* of `encapsulation`. If you don't want that, make it a nested class instead, by adding a `static` modifier:

```
public class encapsulation {
    static class Emp {
    ......
```

Now that `Emp` is declared `static`, it does not belong to any particular instance of `encapsulation`, so you don't need to instantiate `encapsulation` to instantiate `Emp`.

Comment: @ErPriyatam Glad to be of service.